# How can I find unused libraries in a Symfony project with PhpStorm?

Tags: symfony, refactoring, phpstorm, silex

I try to find and also to delete all the unused libraries in a project. For example I have a folder `lib/` with lot of other folder which are the famous libraries. I want to know how I can identify which libraries are not used.

I asked the same question [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000328410-How-can-I-find-unused-libraries-in-a-project) but the only response I received suggests to me to check each file one by one ...

Can you help me?

Comment: remove them, and see what breaks :)

Comment: it's a very hudge project, I can't process like that, but thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, as some libraries may be lazy loaded depending on some internal state of your application.

So even if you could somehow find all *strong typed references* inspecting the code, you have no way of finding out if a library is loaded via magic methods, custom class loaders, dynamically generated `include` or `require` statement, `eval`-ed code and so on.

Without having tests with 95%+ coverage for your *non-library code*, it is very risky to remove anything from your lib folder. You code may appear to run fine, but still fail in some edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open source project that can help you to do that:
https://github.com/composer-unused/composer-unused

**Installation**

```
composer require composer-unused/composer-unused-plugin
```

**Usage**

```
composer unused
```

And if you want to use it inside phpstorm, you can look at their composer documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-the-composer-dependency-manager.html#create-and-run-composer-scripts